# Is it possible to initialize a static final variable from a configuration file in Java?

Tags: java, configuration, constants, final

I'd like to initialize a static final variable from configuration file, in Java. The variable is such that:

```
public static final String SCHEMA = "my_schema";
```

Since the schema can change, I'd like to read it from configuration file. However, I must use a final variable because there's no other way in JPA to inizialize "schema" attribute in "Table" annotation. The point is that because of past choices each environment has been located in the same DB with different schema names.

Comment: Why would the schema change?

Comment: in relation to the environment

Comment: Do you mean your dev environment and prod environment are in different schemas, instead of different databases? Normally the schema doesn't change, just like table names and column names don't change.

Comment: @Kayaman, unfortunately, yes, I mean the dev environment and prod envorinment are in different schemas. Not my choice.

Comment: Well, that sucks, and no it's not possible. Final variables are compile time things, and even if you modified the value through reflection, it wouldn't affect the annotations.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and no, final variables are not compile-time things, and yes, there is a one-liner: see `java.util.ResourceBundle`.

Comment: @user207421 are you saying you can do `@Table(name = "tablename", schema = ResourceBundle.get("schemaname"))`? I meant they're resolved at compiletime, so if you were to use a constant for those, they would keep their original compiletime values.

Answer (score -1):

**UPD** - edited for a better solution

The only work-around I can think of is by having another not final private String variable and a static init block **before** the line with your final variable. For example the following code will yield different final variable after initialization

```
public class TestSmth {

    private static String yourCustomSchema;
    static {
       yourCustomSchema = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "my_schema" : "another_schema";
     }

    public static final String SCHEMA = yourCustomSchema;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SCHEMA);
    }
}
```

You should implement config file loading in the static block

This way after the class is loaded you have your final variable initialized and have no access to the non-final private variable.